# SQL fails to compare strings (false positive)

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I'm trying to do a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM nomencla_base_Distribuye_Participantes_Escala 
WHERE practica = 'OCT' 
  AND temporal IS NULL OR temporal = 0
```

but it returns these values which are not desired:

```
OCTB    3   1000.00  ....
OCTB    3   700.00   ....
OCTB    3   -1.00    ....
```

Why does SQL think 'OCT' equals 'OCTB'? Even using `len(practica)` and `len('OCT')` gives a different result.

Column in the table is a `varchar(50)`

Comment: SQL Server does *not* "think" that `'OCT'` equals `'OCTB'`.  Either your query is wrong or your interpretation of the results is wrong.  For instance, perhaps the first column is not `practica`.

Comment: You will get this result if you use `LIKE` operator not `=` operator. are you sure?

Comment: Your query is obviously wrong because it doesn't even have a 'FROM' in it

Comment: nah, just mistaken when i typed the question, the original querry is
SELECT * from nomencla_base_Distribuye_Participantes_Escala WHERE practica='OCT' AND temporal is null or temporal=0

Comment: @MarianoGNU OR/AND being evaluated differently to how you expect is your problem then. Try this: SELECT * from nomencla_base_Distribuye_Participantes_Escala WHERE practica='OCT' AND (temporal is null or temporal=0)

Answer (score 2):

SQL evaluates AND before OR, so your query as written is effectively:

```
SELECT * 
from nomencla_base_Distribuye_Participantes_Escala 
WHERE (practica='OCT' AND temporal is null) or temporal=0
```

which will return any rows where temporal = 0, regardless of the value of practica. Add brackets to control query behaviour:

```
SELECT * 
from nomencla_base_Distribuye_Participantes_Escala 
WHERE practica='OCT' AND (temporal is null or temporal=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the real reason, I forgot yo use `( )`.

The valid query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM nomencla_base_Distribuye_Participantes_Escala 
WHERE practica = 'OCT' AND (temporal IS NULL OR temporal = 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should work as you are expecting, try it and let me know if it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * 
from nomencla_base_Distribuye_Participantes_Escala 
WHERE practica='OCT' AND isnull(temporal, 0) = 0
```

For more info about ISNULL() function go to:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE practica like 'OCT';
```

here suppose practica varchar datatype.

Comment: same result, as mentioned above that was not the original querry, the original is

SELECT * from nomencla_base_Distribuye_Participantes_Escala WHERE practica like 'OCT' AND temporal is null or temporal=0;

and the result is

log_sql practica idProfesional desde hasta valor enPesos temporal
NULL OCTB 3 1000.00 1333.00 66.00 0 0
NULL OCTB 3 700.00 999.00 600.00 1 0
NULL OCTB 3 -1.00 -1.00 70.00 0 0

Comment: i hate how stack overflow deletes the spaces and eol -_-